# How can i fill canvas other than circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, media

I want to fill the canvas with black color. I have used below code to fill the canvas.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle='rgba(0,0,0,0.1)';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
```

I have a requirement that needs to draw a circle on canvas. I have used below code to draw a circle.

```
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeStyle='red';
ctx.arc(150,75,50,0,2*Math.PI,false);
ctx.stroke();
```

I have a video tag under the canvas element. I want to display video through the circle. I don't want want to fill the circle because if we fill the circle we could not show the video. Other than circle I want to fill. I filled transparent color to circle but it is not showing the video. It is showing the color which is filled to the canvas.

My requirement is I have to display video through the circle.

Please help me how can I achieve this.

Comment: you can first fill the rect and then fill the circle

Comment: I am doing the same thing first I am filling the rect and then circle. I want to apply transparent color to circle. If i apply transparent color then the color which is filled to rect is displaying. My requirement is i want to show the elements under the canvas through circle.

Answer (score 1):

just change`ctx.stroke()` to `ctx.fill()`, for detail see this page: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fill.asp